# java could not find or load main class, using -cp . package.class

Tags: java

I seem to have a problem executing a java class;

I have a static method `main(String[] args){};`

The class is called `Test`, in the package `ptest`

I place the file `Test.class` in the folder `C:\Test\`

Then, I navigate to this location in the command prompt.

Finally, in the command line, I run the following: "java -cp . ptest.Test"

This returns:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ptest.Test
```

What am I missing at this point? What else could be causing this error? What I am doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new folder `C:\Test\ptest`, move `Test.class` to `c:\Test\ptest\Test.class`. `cd\Test`, then `java -cp . ptest.Test`

The package structure corresponds to the output directory structure.

From [Managing Source and Class Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) (The Java Tutorials),

> Put the source code for a class, interface, enumeration, or annotation type in a text file whose name is the simple name of the type and whose extension is .java. For example:
>
> ```
>  //in the Rectangle.java file 
>  package graphics;
>  public class Rectangle {
>     ... 
>  }
> ```
>
> Then, put the source file in a directory whose name reflects the name of the package to which the type belongs:
>
> .....\graphics\Rectangle.java
>
> The qualified name of the package member and the path name to the file are parallel, assuming the Microsoft Windows file name separator backslash (for UNIX, use the forward slash).
>
> ```
>  class name – graphics.Rectangle
>  pathname to file – graphics\Rectangle.java
> ```

Comment: This works, I created the package folder and placed my class file there. Then I returned to the root folder and executed `java -cp . ptest.Test` from `C:\Test`. Thank you! (will be accepting ASAP!)

Answer (score 1):

Packages map to folders in thee filesystem.

Therefore, `ptest.Test` maps to `ptest/Test.class` anywhere in your classpath.